# Which ASP.NET server controls to use?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Trying to learn ASP.NET (with several years of classic ASP development under the belt), and struggling with the myriad server controls for rendering data.

I'm trying to pivot data using server-side data objects.  A good example is a table of Customers with three columns:  1) customer id, 2) customer name 3) nested list of Order ids.  There is, of course, a one-to-many relationship between Customers and Orders.  In classic ASP, I would have used two arrays--one for Customers and one for Orders--and I would have iterated through the Orders array once for each iteration of the Customers array, pulling out the appropriate Order records as needed.

Instead, I'm trying to take advantage of the .NET framework controls, so I'm thinking that I'll dump the Orders into a DataTable, and then I'll create a GridView for the Customers data, with a custom TemplateField that calls to a sub that loops through the Orders DataTable and binds the right records to some sort of object (ListView?  Literal?) that then gets bound to the appropriate row in the Customers GridView.

Is this right?  Am I picking the right controls to use for this purpose?  I'm tempted to just use VB arrays and do it the way I've always done it (mashing together a string of HTML with repeated concatenations), but I'm trying to make an effort to harness the efficiency of the framework.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Since you're used to Classic ASP, I would highly recommend skipping over ASP.NET Web Forms (and all the server controls) and instead go for ASP.NET MVC 3, with the [Razor view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)

Comment: Interesting.  I was thinking that I would first learn the Web Forms controls, and then move into MVC.  But it sounds like you'd suggest otherwise?

Comment: Being an all time web forms guy, it is a bit hard to catch up with MVC. Because Web Forms made life so easy (drag and drop!) And going straight back to HTML and loops was actually hard. BUT, because you are thorough with classic ASP, I believe MVC would treat you just right! Check http://www.asp.net/mvc , there are awesome video tutorials! And Razor Engine is just plain awesome! :)

Comment: Yup. It's not that Web Forms is bad or anything, it's just that it encapsulates so much about the markup and HTTP protocol, and it seems clumsy at times. The server side markup with Razor is pretty similar, the main difference being the type system, and you've got a way better editor with code completion and all that.

Comment: WebForms and MVC are two vastly different ways of doing things.  MVC is a more "web oriented" way of developing app whereas working with WebForms feels more like you're developing a desktop style app.  In either case, they both have their place.  There are situations where MVC is overkill for some situations, and vice-versa.  Regardless, it won't hurt if you spend some time with both and decide what feels more natural to you.  With that being said, MVC is the "new kid on the block" but still a pretty slick framework to with with.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are on the right track.  Some sort of Master/Details setup should do the trick for you and should be very very easy to link together.

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs

This seems like a great start to me, and I defiantly think that the investment with the new controls will pay off in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Pluralsight.com have a great course for ASP.NET Web Forms which should get you on a solid grounding using the ASP.NET framework.

[Building Applications with ASP.NET 4 WebForms](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)

In particular, I would check out Working With DataSource Controls, which is more relevant to what you are trying to achieve.